# I have these libraries on same page materialize js and jquery-ui, the have same function autocomplete, how can I use only jquery-ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, materialize

How to avoid conflict with materialize js autocomplete function with jquery-ui autocomplete function on same page.

Comment: Load jQuery after materialize, this should overwrite the function

Comment: Or use different NameSpace for each.